# Error deploying java callout sample

Tags: apigee

I tried following the steps in https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/doc-samples/java-cookbook and I'm getting an error during deployment:

```
Deploy failed with status 500:
{
  "message" : "com/apigee/CityLookup : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0",
  "contexts" : [ ]
}
```

The compilation and overall bundle creation seems to work (I see the proxy created in the UI), but the error comes at deployment time. I've also tried deploying from the UI and get the same error.

Comment: Free or Enterprise org? Can't do Java in Free...

Comment: Hi Michael, I was initially trying on a free org, and just now tried on an enterprise (paid) org with the same error.  I'd imagine that the error should be different if the problem was that the policy is not supported in the free world, versus the java error on the version

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the version of Java used to compile the java code.

Please compile with Java 6 and then do the deployment. If Java 6 was used for compiling the java classes, then you would end up with this error during deployment.

Comment: As Divya mentioned version 51 is java 7. Take a look at Java class version http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file. Java 6 is version 50.